# Javascript logic syntax

Tags: javascript

My task was to create an object/class called `MrFreeze` and mark this object as frozen so that no other changes can be made to it.]
I came up with the following solution which worked:

```
Object.freeze(MrFreeze);
```

But then as I viewed the solutions provided on http://www.codewars.com I came across this code:

```
(Object.freeze || object)(MrFreeze);
```

I fail to understand this line of code. Please explain why this works when using a OR object operator.

Comment: please Explain ***this*** javascript function?

Comment: this is my working code and i understand it                      Object.freeze(MrFreeze),BUT                                            I need explanation on this  line of code:                  (Object.freeze || object) (MrFreeze)

Comment: You need to add some supporting code to help people understand the context and therefore be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a fallback to me.

when Object.freeze does exist it performs:

```
Object.freeze(MrFreeze);
```

when Object.freeze doesn't exist it performs:

```
object(MrFreeze);
```

This might as well be written as (more verbose for clearification):

```
function freeze(MrFreeze, object) {
    if (Object.freeze) {
        Object.freeze(MrFreeze);
    }
    else {
        object(MrFreeze);
    }
}
```